# Looking for backend server for appointment management component of project

Tags: api, calendar, server, scheduling, web-apis

I am trying to locate a back-end component to provide a RESTful api that allows users to schedule appointments with multiple resources. I am trying desperately not to have to write it. It must meet the following requirements.

1. Allow multiple resources to define a regular, recurring availability schedule for each resource ie 9-5 M-F and lunch break from 12-1
2. The ability to schedule exceptions for time off.
3. Respond to query to provide the time of the next available appointment for any resource or a specific resource.
4. Return list of all appointments in a data range
5. Return list all available appointments in a date range

There are several SaaS providers that claim this functionality but we want to keep it in house.  Prefer open source but commercial is an option too.

The frontend project is react and react-native and the backend is currently nginx/php-fpm.  We will develop the UI, just need a backend provider to integrate into the project.

I'm also interested in libraries, modules or frameworks that may reduce the scope of developing it in house.